# Bootstrap collapse needs two clicks to open on a Joomla site

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

In this Joomla page http://185.25.22.156/petshop.gr/index.php/blog 
you have to initially press twice the "Show More" button to get Bootstrap collapse plugin to show the collapsible content. 
Then the button works (show/hide the collapsible content) with one click as it supposed to.

Here is my Joomla's article html

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="category">Blog
        <button type="button" class="btn-arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#subcategory">Show More
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
    </h1>
    <div id="subcategory" class="container collapse">
        <div id="subcategories">
            <div class="row" style="margin: 30px 0 0 0;">More content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script>     
    $jq1('#subcategory').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
      $jq1(".btn-arrow").html('Show More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>');  
    });
    $jq1('#subcategory').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
      $jq1(".btn-arrow").html('Show Less <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>');
    });
</script>
```

Any help will be very much appreciated!!!

Comment: Your posted code is fine. Copy/paste your code into https://jsfiddle.net/hf2rerL6/ works on first click. Problem must be elsewhere. Btw. collapse is not really needed here. Greetings to Greece.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Toni. 
Indeed collapse is not really needed here but I use the same code here http://185.25.22.156/petshop.gr/index.php/skylos which is writen in greek!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are clicking first time than this attribute gets added to the button

```
aria-expanded="false"
```

So the div gets collapsed, if expanded. When you click second time it becomes

```
aria-expanded="true"
```

The div gets expanded if it is collapsed. So Only when it becomes true the div is expanded. You need to check which javascript is adding this extra attribute. You have to make the first click true and second false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Amit Ray. Any suggestion - links how to check javascript adding this extra attribute? I am novice.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem even I was set the `aria-expanded=true`.if you want it is open by default,add `show` class to collapse content and set `aria-expanded=true`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case using BootStrap "5.0.2", not an issue with bootstrap rather in the button "data-bs-target" and div tag I had special characters #AMCVS_4DD80861515CAB990A490D45%40AdobeOrg (%40 I have to replace that character to solve  it)

Html sample:

```
<div class="accordion-item">
                    <h6 class="accordion-header" id="AMCVS_4DD80861515CAB990A490D45%40AdobeOrg+1">
                        <button type="button" class="accordion-button collapsed" style="height:10px" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#AMCVS_4DD80861515CAB990A490D45%40AdobeOrg">
                            AMCVS_4DD80861515CAB990A490D45%40AdobeOrg
                        </button>
                    </h6>
                    <div id="AMCVS_4DD80861515CAB990A490D45%40AdobeOrg" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#cookieAccordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card-header py-0">
                                <small>Cookie: AMCVS_4DD80861515CAB990A490D45%40AdobeOrg</small>
                                <svg style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="copyTextToClipboard('1')" title="Copy AppSettings" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" fill="currentColor" class="ms-1 bi bi-clipboard" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M4 1.5H3a2 2 0 0 0-2 2V14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V3.5a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-1v1h1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1V14a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h1v-1z"></path>
                                    <path d="M9.5 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h3zm-3-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 5 1.5v1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 6.5 4h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 11 2.5v-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 9.5 0h-3z"></path>
                                </svg> <div class="d-inline"><small class="text-muted">Raw</small></div>
                                <svg style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="copyTextToClipboard('')" title="Copy AppSettings" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" fill="currentColor" class="ms-1 bi bi-clipboard" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M4 1.5H3a2 2 0 0 0-2 2V14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V3.5a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-1v1h1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1V14a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h1v-1z"></path>
                                    <path d="M9.5 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h3zm-3-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 5 1.5v1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 6.5 4h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 11 2.5v-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 9.5 0h-3z"></path>
                                </svg><div class="d-inline"><small class="text-muted"> Json</small></div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="ms-0 mt-0 border card-body py-1" style="height: auto; width:auto">
                                    <small>1</small>
                                    </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```